# Create a List which has minimum elements and at least one common element from a group of Lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a collection of lists of integers. I want to create a new list which has a minimum number of elements and has at least one common element with each of the lists.

Example:

```
List_A = [1,2,3] 
List_B = [3,4,6] 
List_C = [4,5]
```

A possible solution in this example would be `[3,4]` (or `[1,4]` or `[3,5]` amongst others).

What is the optimal way to do the above task?

Comment: The solution should consider just 3 list or a random amount of lists?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre any random amount of lists

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: This is the Hitting Set Problem which is NP-complete. https://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs267/lecture5.pdf

Comment: @MoB. Details mentioned in the paper is matching the requirements. Will try to go through them. Thanks

Comment: Even though it's NP-hard, integer programming works well in practice.